# Obtener división de los niveles de un mismo factor para generar una nueva estructura de datos

Tags: r

Dispongo de una base de datos de este tipo (aquí una muestra mínima que contendría los datos de dos simulaciones para cada ronda, nivel y condición):

**Datos editados:**

```
df <- data.frame(Sim=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),Ronda=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),Condicion=c('A1','A1','A2','A2','A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B1','B2','B2','B1','B1','B2','B2','A1','A1','A2','A2','A1','A1','A2','A2','B1','B1','B2','B2','B1','B1','B2','B2'),Nivel=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),Salida=c(3,2.5,2.1,1.9,2.8,2.3,2.0,1.6,2.6,2.7,1.3,1.2,2.4,2.3,1,1.1,2,1.3,1.3,0.9,2,2.1,2.1,1.2,2,1.7,1.2,1,2,1.3,0.5,0.4))
```

Me gustaría ahora manipular esta base de datos para obtener la reducción relativa que, en orden, la "Salida" correspondiente a A2 produce en A1 (1-(A2/A1), y B2 en B1 (1-(B2/B1), para cada simulación, Ronda y Nivel. En otras palabras, se busca obtener el porcentaje de reducción que n2 produce en n1.

Por lo tanto, lo que se busca generar es algo así:

```
Ronda    Condición    Nivel   Resultado
1        1-(A2/A1)      1        0.3
1        1-(A2/A1)      1        0.24
...
1        1-(B2/B1)      2        0.5
1        1-(B2/B1)      2        0.56
...
2        1-(A2/A1)      1
2        1-(A2/A1)      1
...
2        1-(B2/B1)      1
2        1-(B2/B1)      1
...
```

Mis intentos por ahora han ido encaminados a operar utilizar `subset` de datos e intentar hacer cálculos con `tapply`. Agradezco ayuda.

**Edición segunda:**

[Aquí](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ju2evswljmb2h70/data_homo.csv?dl=0) hay un ejemplo de datos reales. El objetivo es el mismo. En este caso *Condición* es un factor con 6 niveles. Se pretende por lo tanto crear un nuevo dataframe que contenga Simulation, Round, Cofactor y las nuevas columnas: "Resultado" y "Nueva Condición" (una condición nueva con 3 niveles). Por ejemplo:

```
A=(1-(Heterogeneity OTA/Homogeneity OTA)
B=(1-(Heterogeneity C/Homogeneity C)
C=(1-(Heterogeneity PR/Homogeneity PR)
```

Esto permitiría que pueda graficar fácilmente los datos posteriormente.

Comment: 1) Revisando los datos que subiste veo que los datos están octuplicados. `data_homo %>% distinct()` me da nrow = 115,500, es decir, ese es el número de combinaciones únicas de  Simulation, Round, Condition, Output, Cofactor.  ¿Eso está bien así o es un error en la fuente de datos que hay que arreglar primero?

Comment: Puse una respuesta para los datos reales. Aviso: el resultado produce valores `-Inf`. Deberías diagnosticarlo, no sé si es un resultado esperado, un problema en los datos o si el código de mi respuesta está mal y los produce por error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Abajo una respuesta para los datos reales.

Va una solución con el `dlyr` y `tidyr`. La idea es pasar a formato ancho, de modo que quede una columna para cada Condición (A1, A2, B1, B2), después es fácil hacer la operación que división y resta.

El problema que encontré es que no había un identificador para las simulaciones. En tus datos de ejemplo por cada grupo de Ronda, Nivel y Condición quedaban dos filas.

Asumí que cada fila correspondía a una simulación diferente y les puse un identificador único. Si en tus datos reales tienes un identificador de simulación/paciente/lo que sea deberías usar ese identificador. La idea es que cada grupo sea único.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, Nivel, Condicion) %>% 
  mutate(simulacion = 1:n()) %>%              #Aquí agrego un identificador de simulación
  spread(key = Condicion, value = Salida) %>% 
  mutate(A = 1-(A2/A1), 
         B = 1-(B2/B1)) %>%                   #Acá ya está el resultado
  gather(condicion, resultado, A, B).         #Solo para que se vea como lo que se indica en la pregunta.

# A tibble: 16 x 9
# Groups:   Ronda, Nivel [4]
Ronda Nivel simulacion    A1    A2    B1    B2 condicion resultado
<dbl> <dbl>      <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
1     1     1          1   3     2.1   2.6   1.3 A             0.300
2     1     1          2   2.5   1.9   2.7   1.2 A             0.24 
3     1     2          1   2.8   2     2.4   1   A             0.286
```

Si tus datos están muy limpios y podes confiar en el orden alfabético de `Condición` la siguiente alternativa funcionaría para un número arbitrario de grupos de `Condición`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Ronda, Nivel, Condicion) %>% 
  mutate(simulacion = 1:n()) %>% 
  arrange(Ronda, Nivel, simulacion, Condicion) %>% 
  separate(Condicion, into = c("Letra", "Número"), sep = 1) %>% #OJO ACÁ: separa por posición!!
  group_by(Ronda, Nivel, simulacion, Letra) %>% 
  mutate(Resultado = 1-Salida/lag(Salida))
```

Aunque debería tener cuidado con el separador en la 5ta línea que es completamente ad hoc.

> `spread()` tiene mala fama por el mensaje de error `Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.`, que a veces puede ser frustrante. Pero en realidad es buen reaseguro que facilita identificar problemas en los datos. En este caso que había un dato (simulación) no identificado.

## Respuesta con los datos reales

### Diagnóstico

Revisando los datos veo que están octuplicados

```
data_homo %>% distinct() %>% nrow()
[1] 115500
115500*8
[1] 924000 #Es el nrow del dataframe original
```

Quizás a estos datos que subiste les falte alguna columna que separa a esos grupos de 8, pero así como están esa información es redundante. En la respuesta uso `distinct()` para eliminar filas repetidas. De lo contrario `spread()` fallará (y con razón).

### Solución

Con los datos reales está complicado usar la aproximación `x/lag(x)`, porque depende del orden alfabético o numérico y en este caso no hay un orden "natural", como sería el caso cuando trabajamos con fechas.

Considerando que ya sabes los cálculos quieres hacer creo que la mejor solución es

1. pasarlo a datos anchos: una columna por cada nivel del factor Condition
2. hacer un `mutate()` en el que se especifiquen los cálculos sobre esas columnas.
3. Como el resultado va a ser "ancho", pasar a largo de nuevo con `gather()`.

Uso la función `clean_names()` del paquete `janitor::` para evitar tener que envolver en ` los nombres con espacios. Es opcional, pero si lo no usas deberías corregir los nombres de columnas en el `mutate()` de la línea 5.

```
data_homo %>% 
  distinct() %>%                                   #Porque los datos están octuplicados
  spread(key = Condition, value = Output) %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%                       #Para eliminar espacios en los nombres y normaliza a minúsculas
  mutate(A=1-(heterogeneity_ota/homogeneity_ota),  #Dejé los nombres ABC pq no sé que iría ahí realmente. Pero está claro que hace cada operación
         B=1-(heterogeneity_c/  homogeneity_c),
         C=1-(heterogeneity_pr/ homogeneity_pr)) %>% 
  select(simulation, round, cofactor, A, B, C) %>% 
  gather(resultado, nueva_condicion, A, B, C)
```

El resultado creo que es el que buscas, sin embargo revisando los resultados en el `tail()` aparecen unos `-Inf` (infinitos negativos), seguramente porque hay divisiones entre 0 y R las maneja como números infinitos.

Con `filter (nueva_condicion == -Inf)` se puede ver que son 2303 filas potencialmente problemáticas, sobre todo si planeas graficar después.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. En efecto, olvidé añadir una columna para identificar cada simulación. Ya está editado. El problema que tengo es que este separador no estaría funcionando para mi caso real. Los niveles de mi factor son 6, y denominados `("Homogeneity OTA", "Heterogeneity OTA", "Homogeneity C", "Heterogeneity C", "Homogeneity PR","Heterogeneity PR")`. Donde "A1" sería "Homogeneity OTA", "A2" sería "Heterogeneity OTA", y así... Quizá hubiera sido mejor subir una muestra de datos en lugar del ejemplo mínimo.

Comment: Creo que sería buena subir al menos parte de los datos. De todos modos prueba con `separate(Condicion, into = c("clave1", "clave2"))`, que debería detectar automáticamente al espacio como separador. Y cambiar los nombres, les puse `clave2` porque no sería `OTA`, `C` y `PR` en el contexto en que lo usas.

Comment: En la respuesta original usé la posición como separador (eso hace `sep = 1`) porque `A1` no me permitía usar un carácter como separador.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Sí, creo que esto funciona, pero tengo problemas para implementarlo con mis datos. Aunque es bastante pesado, he decidido subir un ejemplo de simulación en csv a dropbox.

Comment: @malpadrino, gracias por la respuesta, muy buena como siempre. Los datos, como muy bien apuntas, están octuplicados. Esto es debido a que se obtienen de simulaciones con 8 agentes, y en este caso la "cognición" que se aplicó a cada agente es la misma, de ahí la copia. No obstante, se pueden filtrar esto. En cuanto al graficado, sí, me dio problemas, así que tuve que operar con la media del conjunto de datos en lugar de con los nuevos outputs, pues -inf genera problemas, claro. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, entiendo igual que @mpaladino, que hay información duplicada, hay 8 filas idénticas por observación. En primer lugar, eliminamos estos duplicados, aunque técnicamente no es necesario, pero si es importante regenerar un `id` para cada grupos de observaciones de la siguiente forma:

```
df <- read.csv('~/Descargas/data_homo.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df %>% 
    select(-X) %>% 
    distinct()  %>% 
    group_by(Simulation, Round, Condition) %>% 
    mutate(nr = row_number()) -> new_df

new_df

# A tibble: 63,000 x 6
# Groups:   Simulation, Round, Condition [10,500]
   Simulation Round Condition         Output Cofactor    nr
        <int> <int> <chr>              <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      0       1
 2          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      0.2     2
 3          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      0.4     3
 4          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      0.6     4
 5          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      0.8     5
 6          1     1 Homogeneity OTA        3      1       6
 7          1     1 Heterogeneity OTA      3      0       1
 8          1     1 Heterogeneity OTA      3      0.2     2
 9          1     1 Heterogeneity OTA      3      0.4     3
10          1     1 Heterogeneity OTA      3      0.6     4
# ... with 62,990 more rows
```

Ahora bien, una forma de resolverlo es pensando el problema con la óptica de bases de datos relacionales. La idea es, partir de un tabla maestra que nos indica las relaciones existentes. Como son tres las relaciones, no es difícil definirlas manualmente:

```
condiciones <- data.frame(new_cond = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                          from = c('Homogeneity OTA', 'Homogeneity C', 'Homogeneity PR'),
                          to = c('Heterogeneity OTA', 'Heterogeneity C', 'Heterogeneity PR'),
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
condiciones

new_cond            from                to
1        A Homogeneity OTA Heterogeneity OTA
2        B   Homogeneity C   Heterogeneity C
3        C  Homogeneity PR  Heterogeneity PR
```

Con esta "tabla maestra" simplemente deberemos plantear `joins` que nos unan cada observación en una única fila para luego simplemente hacer los cálculos. Esto es bastante práctico por que, si eventualmente muestras todas las variables, podremos verificar el resultado manualmente.

```
condiciones %>% 
    inner_join(new_df, by=c("from" = "Condition")) %>% 
    inner_join(new_df, by=c("to" = "Condition",
                            "Simulation" = "Simulation",
                            "Round" = "Round",
                            "nr" = "nr")
               ) %>% 
    mutate(Resultado = 1 - (Output.y/Output.x)) %>% 
    select(new_cond, Simulation, Round, Resultado) %>% 
    sample_n(10)

      new_cond Simulation Round   Resultado
8615         A        206     1  0.00000000
20523        B        239     5  0.22222222
6896         A        165     2  0.16666667
8859         A        211     7 -1.03117261
23279        C         55     2  0.10000000
5987         A        143     4 -0.39458360
2496         A         60     3 -0.12991072
11193        B         17     4  0.04193819
11764        B         31     1  0.00000000
22463        C         35     6  0.18817578
```

Comment: @Patrico Moracho, muchas gracias por esta excelente solución. Al final he utilizado una versión de esto mismo. He introducido un cambio en `mutate(Resultado = 1 - (Output.x/Output.y)` ya que al graficar me di cuenta de que la división la tenía invertida. Finalmente, calculé una media para cada nivel de condición y después utilicé este mismo código para generar el nuevo dataframe y graficar. Funciona. Es un lujo contar con vosotros en la versión stackoverlow en español (que supera en muchas veces la inglesa en concisión, detalle y ayuda).